# Symfony4: Gos Websocket Error: MySQL server has gone away

Tags: symfony, pdo, websocket, symfony4

I have enabled the PDO Periodic Pings for GOS:WebSocketBundle, I'm still getting this error from time to time:

```
 09:41:28 ERROR [websocket] Connection error occurred Warning: Error
 while sending QUERY packet. PID=30536 in /home/dev.symfony/libs/composer_vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php
 10:00:23 ERROR     [websocket] Connection error occurred
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away in
 /home/dev.symfony/libs/composer_vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php
 line 107 ["connection_id" => 3365,"session_id" =>
 "11667050395acf121709d30728596936"] []
```

Another point is that if nobody use dev server, in logs no errors, but if I login to this immediatelly appear this error.

There is issue opened also on github https://github.com/GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle/issues/299
but no answers, so I asked also here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Problem was that I defined periodic timer inside Topic inside "onSubscribe" funciton like:

```
public function onSubscribe(ConnectionInterface $connection, Topic $topic, WampRequest $request)
    {
...
        $topicTimer = $connection->PeriodicTimer;

        //Add periodic timer every 3 seconds update
        $topicTimer->addPeriodicTimer('notifications', 3, function() use ($topic, $connection) {
            $user = $this->clientManipulator->getClient($connection);
            if($user) {
                $counters = $this->globalVariables->getCounters($user);
                $connection->event($topic->getId(),['msg' => $counters]);
            }
        });
...
    }
```

But now I switched to "standalone" periodic like it described here https://github.com/GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle/blob/master/Periodic/PdoPeriodicPing.php
and attached this to websocket. Now there is no timeout with database.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that when you follow the Symfony documentation with creating PdoSessionHandler http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/pdo_session_storage.html where you are passing the dsn instead of pdo service it won't work, because the session handler will create other connection. To solve this create a pdo service and pass it to the PdoSessionHandler like it is described in the https://github.com/GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle/blob/master/Resources/docs/SessionSetup.md